# mysql_fetch_row and ORDER BY - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Sorry for the vague title, but I've been trying to nail this for a week and have run out of ideas.

Table: name: `scores`

```
 id name    password    intuition   
 (int, varchar, varchar, int)
 (5 rows with made-up values)
```

The PHP:

```
$userResult = mysql_query("SELECT `intuition` FROM `scores` ORDER BY `intuition` DESC LIMIT 4,1");      
if($userResult ==NULL)
{   die(mysql_error());
}else
{   if($userResult ==FALSE)
    {   die("ranking query failed, sorry");
        }else
        {   if(mysql_num_rows($userResult) ==NULL)  
                {   die("No ranking results found.");       
            }else
            {   $queryRow   = mysql_fetch_row($userResult);
                $topIntuition   = $query_row['intuition'];
                die("queryRow =$queryRow;  topIntuition =$topIntuition");
        }
        }
}
```

Output:

```
query row =Array; topIntuition =
```

where `topIntuition` should be the fifth highest result, currently the integer 2. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: `$query_row[<name of row>]` does not work, but `$query_row[0]` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIMIT 4, 1 will return the fifth highest result (as LIMIT 0, 1 returns the first).

Regardless, `mysql_fetch_row` returns an array with keys that are numeric - try $queryRow[0];

Alternatively, you can switch to `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Edited. But it should still return the value "2" - the table contains "intuition" values 2,5,42,3,2

Comment: Try doing `print_r($userResult);` to see what is in the array.

Comment: "print_r($userResult);" returns "Resource id #3" - I assume this means the data is there but I have not asked in the right way? But all my Googling indicates that what I have typed should be all I need.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `print_r($queryRow);`. I've edited my original with the correct answer anyway.

Comment: EDIT: "print_r($query_row)" returns "Array ( [0] => 2 )" - now I need to Google to find out what that means